# Batch deleting working for one sub directory but not another

Tags: batch-file

So I have two related things that I want to delete after 3 months of inactivity. My arguments are all correct, its the pathing I can't figure out. I have two lines of code in this batch file:

```
PushD "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Air Check" &&(forfiles -s -m *.* -d -90 -c "cmd /c del /q @path") & PopD
```

That line works. It does what it is supposed to do, and now I want to do the exact same thing with just one slight difference:

```
PushD "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Archive\Air Check" &&(forfiles -s -m *.* -d -90 -c "cmd /c del /q @path") & PopD
```

As you can see the *only* difference is the `\Archive` in the path. However, when the batch file gets to that line it gives me this output: 
`Could Not Find: V:\Radio Productions\Archive\Air Check\.DS_Store
Could Not Find V:\Radio Productions\Archive\Air Check\2016.DS_Store` 
I don't have a `V:` drive, nor do I know what the heck `.DS_Store` means. 
Thoughts?

Comment: Pushd creates a temporary mapping on Network shares, popd removes it. `.DS_Store` are remnants from MacOS accessing the share (in Linux/MacOS files starting with a dot are usually hidden).

Comment: @LotPings Thanks for letting me know, I didn't know that. The only thing is I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Straight from the help for the `PUSHD` command which is only 11 lines long. **If Command Extensions are enabled the PUSHD command accepts
network paths in addition to the normal drive letter and path.
If a network path is specified, PUSHD will create a temporary
drive letter that points to that specified network resource and
then change the current drive and directory, using the newly
defined drive letter.  Temporary drive letters are allocated from
Z: on down, using the first unused drive letter found.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is working, just not deleting those two files. This is because they have the hidden attribute set. If you need them to be deleted regardless of attributes (system/hidden/read only) change your code to

```
PushD "\\wideorbit.byui.edu\d\Radio Productions\Archive\Air Check" &&(forfiles -s -m *.* -d -90 -c "cmd /c del /q /a /f @path") & PopD
```